# Socket.IO sends disconnect event to server after reconnection

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

**Context:**
I am building a real time game play platform in react. For that I'm using socket.IO in react frontend (socket.io-client: v4.1.3) and node js backend (socket.io: v4.1.3).

**Problem:**
I am facing issue when user gets disconnected because of network issues.
So when user got disconnected, server does not know about that until the next ping interval.
And if user gets connected again before that, it sends connect event to server and then after few seconds, it sends disconnect event.

Because of which in the internal players list, we remove that player. but it shows player as connected in frontend.

Now we cannot detect in server that if the disconnect event is sent for some reason or by mistake.
Is it expected? and how can i not disconnect if the user connects again?

**What I tried:**
I tried adding custom heartbeat in sockets. but as it pings on some interval, it takes some time to detect of user is connected or not. but I don't even want it to get disconnect in the first place.

I have also tried checking socket.connected and socket.in('user_id').fetchSockets, socket.rooms. They all are empty inside disconnect event. but in all other events (even after disconnect), they are not empty. Which means user is connected to sockets. but it fired disconnect event without any reason.

**What I expect:**
I am expecting it to either send disconnect event before connect or not send after connection. How can i achieve this?

Comment: have you tried using socket.on("disconnect",()=>{}); on the server?

Comment: "And if user gets connected again before that, it sends connect event to server and then after few seconds, it sends disconnect event." can you give more explanation regarding that part